# Using an Object based Function within a normal Function in Python

Tags: python, function, oop

I am trying to call an object oriented function, within a (normal) function. I use the (normal) function directly with the object. Firstly, the fact that the outer (normal) function accepts the object seems somewhat counter-intuitive to me. Secondly, the error I get is that the inner object based function is not able to get an object as reference. Here is the code:

```
class Node:
 def __init__(self, time):
    self.time = time


# list to create objects of class Node
sequence = []
for i in range(5): sequence.append(Node(i * 5))


# object based function, created outside the class, and linked to it
def get_time(self):
    return self.time

Node.get_time = get_time()

# output array
arr = [0 for i in range(5)]

# non-object based function, uses object based function to populate arr
def getter(x):
    arr[x] = get_time()

# implementation
for y in range(5):
    sequence[y].getter(y)

for z in range(5): print(arr[z])
```

The error I get is - TypeError: get_time() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: There's several issues here (aside from the indentation). You assign `get_time()`, which is the result of a call to the function, not the function itself. How do you expect `getter()` to have access to `get_time()`, if it's not part of the same class? Why are you defining methods outside the class definition to begin with? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Simply remove the `()` - so like `Node.get_time = get_time`. but then you'll run into another error, looks like at L26.

Comment: @Grismar i did a quick fix up of the indentation, it should be solid now hopefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does everything your code appears to try to do:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time

    def get_time(self):
        return self.time


sequence = [Node(i * 5) for i in range(5)]

arr = [node.get_time() for node in sequence]

print(arr)
```

However, although you would normally define a *method* (a function that's part of a class and operates on instances of that class) like the example above, you *can* define it later as well, although you generally don't need to.

Such a function will get the object it operates on passed as the first argument, which is why `get_time` has `self` as the first parameter - it could be called anything, but `self` is the convention in Python.

So, this does the same:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, time):
        self.time = time


def get_time(self):
    return self.time


# note: "get_time", not "get_time()", assigning the function itself, not the result
Node.get_time = get_time

sequence = [Node(i * 5) for i in range(5)]

arr = [node.get_time() for node in sequence]

print(arr)
```

However, it may give you problems if you later inherit from `Node`, and your editor may not always be aware that `get_time` is now a method of `Node` and generate warnings. Don't do this unless you must.

To answer your question: because `get_item` is assigned to `Node.get_item` and it is a function, it now works as a method on that class, an thus it gets called with an object of the class `Node` as its first argument, when called on that object.

If you want a function to access the object and its contents (attributes and methods), it needs to know about the object and its class, but it can just access it like this:

```
def get_all_times(nodes):
    return [node.get_time() for node in nodes]


arr = get_all_times(sequence)
```

Wherever you have access to an instance of the class, it will have the attributes and methods defined on it, you don't need anything special to access them (other than knowing they are there).

Comment: I am trying to replicate an application in Java. Is it possible to make external functions access objects, and use this to apply object based functions? Why does the external function accept the object in the first place?